# When is it acceptable to exclude data from analysis?

Tags: outliers, filter

I have Alcohol, Tobacco, and Firearms (ATF) trace data that lists categories/offenses related to when a firearm was recovered by law enforcement. However, in many cases there are offenses that are really unusual (e.g. abortion, bribery, extortion) and in others they are simply rare. Over eight years and 50 states, these offenses register to have a mean of less than two and a median of zero.

Given that the upper half of these offenses have a mean greater than 10 and a median of around three. What is the criteria for excluding number of categorical values on the basis that they are low volume or rare?

*The point of this is clearly being missed, so let me rephrase. I have a dataset where categorical variables (offenses, *not* tied to FBI UCR classification) are assigned to the number of weapons being recovered by law enforcement, example below.

| YEAR | STATE | OFFENSE | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | New York | Homicide | 400 |
| 2013 | California | Dangerous Drugs | 300 |
| 2016 | Illinois | Forgery | 20 |
| 2019 | Texas | Abortion | 1 |

There are 68 categories, 11 of which have been removed due to missing data for 4 out of 9 years. The most common is "Possession of a weapon" (mean = 1376, median = 779, max = 17900, min = 8), the least is "Threat to burn" (mean = 0.046, median = 0, max = 2, min = 0). Because my plan is to use this categorical data among other independent variables in a multivariate analysis, I am looking for valid opportunities to reduce/organize the data in a more meaningful sense.

I've attempted to parse this out using violent/non-violent offense categories but weapons seized from "non-violent" categories always shadow "violent" categories, difference is 10,000 or greater over 8 years. Despite creating a new "weapons-related" event from "non-violent" categories, I am getting similar results. Which is why I've turned to k means clustering, but the output is suggesting two clustered groups. Clustering code below:

```
fviz_nbclust(df, kmeans, method = "silhouette", k.max = 10)
```

[image]

```
k1 <- kmeans(df, centers = 2, nstart = 25)
k2 <- kmeans(df, centers = 3, nstart = 25)
k3 <- kmeans(df, centers = 4, nstart = 25)
k4 <- kmeans(df, centers = 5, nstart = 25)

# plots to compare
p1 <- fviz_cluster(k1, geom = "point", data = df)
p2 <- fviz_cluster(k2, geom = "point", data = df)
p3 <- fviz_cluster(k3, geom = "point", data = df)
p4 <- fviz_cluster(k4, geom = "point", data = df)

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, nrow = 2)

wss <- function(k) {
  kmeans(df, k, nstart = 10 )$tot.withinss
}

# Compute and plot wss for k = 1 to k = 15
k.values <- 1:15

# extract wss for 2-15 clusters
wss_values <- map_dbl(k.values, wss)

plot(k.values, wss_values,
     type="b", pch = 19, frame = FALSE, 
     xlab="Number of clusters K",
     ylab="Total within-clusters sum of squares")
```

[image]

```
category <- t(df)
category_dist <- dist(category, method="euclidean")  
fit <- hclust(category_dist, method="ward.D")
plot(fit, family="Arial")
rect.hclust(fit, k=2, border="cadetblue")
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of this analysis? What are you trying to learn, and how does deciding to include/exclude data help you learn it?

Comment: I'm trying to group the offenses into violent or non-violent, or something that makes sense. When performing a k-means cluster analysis, the groupings overlapped each other quite significantly when k > 2.

Comment: Why is deciding whether an offense violent or nonviolent a statistical matter? It seems like that would be described by the data itself -- assault, murder, etc.

Comment: For some of the data, it is easy enough to gather that information. However, the category "suicide" may be considered violent or "property damage" depending on the context.

Comment: This isn’t a statistical question, but how is suicide a crime of property damage? // What statistical analysis do you hope will tell you that murder is violent and insider trading is less so?

Comment: Please see original post for edits

Comment: If the problem is that results are poor for k > 2, that seems to be evidence that k=2 is the choice that's supported by the data.